# Message duplication with PubSubInboundChannelAdapter in Spring Boot with Google PubSub

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

### What I'm trying to do:

I am developing a Spring Boot application that should act as a subscriber for Google PubSub with "Exactly-once delivery" requirement. I have followed all the guidelines mentioned in the Google Cloud documentation for this:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery?_ga=2.207375771.-964146300.1676062320#pubsub_subscriber_exactly_once-java

However, instead of using the PubSub client library directly, I am using Spring Integration.

### Problem:

The problem is that when I use the PubSubInboundChannelAdapter in my application, it is duplicating the same message multiple times with the same Id. My configuration class for PubSubInboundChannelAdapter is shown below:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class PubSubConfig {


    @Value("${values.gcp.pubsub.subscription.name}")
    private String subscriptionName;

    /**
     * This bean enables serialization/deserialization of Java objects to JSON allowing you
     * utilize JSON message payloads in Cloud Pub/Sub.
     *
     * @param objectMapper the object mapper to use
     * @return a Jackson message converter
     */
    @Bean
    public JacksonPubSubMessageConverter jacksonPubSubMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JacksonPubSubMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("pubsubInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
                new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, subscriptionName);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setPayloadType(MyObjectThatNeedBeUnique.class);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO_ACK);

        return adapter;
    }
}
```

And, the listener for this is:

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Component
public class CreateVMListener {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel")
    public void createVMListener(@Payload MyObjectThatNeedBeUnique payload,
                                 @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE) BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message)
            throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException { 
        log.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + payload.toString() + " | MessageId: " + message.getPubsubMessage().getMessageId() );
        // Do some processing that takes 5 min to proccess

    }

}
```

In the application.yml, I have configured the max-ack-extension-period to be 600 seconds and did the same in the Google Cloud PubSub dashboard:

[Screenshot of the google cloud pubsub dashboard showing the Exactly once delivery configuration and the Acknowledgement deadline in 600 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1eCR.png)

#### Log showing the duplication issue:

```
 2023-02-05 23:22:20.055 [thread1] INFO - Message arrived! Payload: MyObjectThatNeedBeUnique (userId=432) | MessageID: 6846773022764035
 2023-02-05 23:22:31.969 [thread2] INFO - Message arrived! Payload: MyObjectThatNeedBeUnique (userId=432) | MessageID: 6846773022764035
 2023-02-05 23:23:33.028 [thread3] INFO - Message arrived! Payload: MyObjectThatNeedBeUnique (userId=432) | MessageID: 6846773022764035
 2023-02-05 23:24:34.055 [thread4] INFO - Message arrived! Payload: MyObjectThatNeedBeUnique (userId=432) | MessageID: 6846773022764035
```

For example, in this log, the same message was repeated 4 times in a short period of time, indicating that 4 threads were simultaneously processing the same information.

#### Questions:

1. Why is this duplication happening?
2. What can I do to prevent duplications while retaining the use of the PubSubInboundChannelAdapter (which offers more efficient streaming pull)?

#### Additional Information: Identifying the Issue

To find the source of the problem, I tried multiple approaches and eventually discovered that the issue was with the PubSubInboundChannelAdapter. I switched to a synchronous option, the PubSubMessageSource (as the code below), which fixed the duplication of messages. However, this solution has a disadvantage as it is synchronous and not as performant as the PubSubInboundChannelAdapter. Because of this I want to know if there is a way to use PubSubInboundChannelAdapter without any duplication problem.

```java
 @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "pubsubInputChannel")
    public MessageSource<Object> pubsubAdapter(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubMessageSource messageSource = new PubSubMessageSource(pubSubTemplate,  createVMSubscriptionName);
        messageSource.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO_ACK);
        messageSource.setPayloadType(CreateOrStartVM.class);
        messageSource.setBlockOnPull(true);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Comment: Are you setting ExactlyOnceDelivery on the subscription itself?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot in the post is from the subscription

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with some peers who were not experiencing the issue on their machines, I realized the problem was in the IntelliJ debug configuration.

The reason why the same message is being duplicated multiple times with the same ID is because the PubSubInboundChannelAdapter is a Stream, and in order to make the Reactive Stream Debugger work properly without bugs, you need to enable Hooks.onOperatorDebug() in IntelliJ:

[Image showing the Reactive Stream configuration in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk8I3.png)

After some extra search, I found that the PubSubInboundChannelAdapter uses Reactive Stream in the background, and to debug reactive streams, you need a tool that can visualize and inspect the events flowing through it.

Comment: I don't get what it has to do with the underlying problem. Did you solve the issue you were facing? Because I have precisely the same problem, and even as I debug and witness that it does ack the messages but the same message keeps coming again and again